# Liquid Slider - Strange margin in Safari only

Tags: slider, liquid

I implemented a jquery Liquid Slider, and while it works fine in Chrome and Firefox, in Safari there is a strange right margin of about ~4 pixel and I can't figure out why?

I hope you can help me here. This is the link to the website:

http://imgda.com/

Thank you in advance!